# Script not working on rich content in Community builder

Tags: lightning-aura-components, community, lightning, community-builder

I am using a `JQuery` script which prompts users if they click on an external link which takes them away from the `community`. I have it loaded in an empty component and i placed the component in the header in `community builder`.
This script works fine on any external links i use in my custom components, however, it doesn't work on external links posted using `"Rich Content Text"` component.

Any idea why this could be? Here is the jquery part:

```
$('a[href^="http"]').click(function() {
   alert('');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work because rich text content is loaded in an iframe. In other words, your script can't intercept the request to click on a link, because they're not even in the same DOM. Instead, you can probably use "[onbeforeunload](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onbeforeunload)" in order to prompt when a user leaves the page. It looks like this:

```
$(window).on('beforeunload', function(e) {
    var dialogText = "Are you sure you want to leave?";
    e.returnValue = dialogText;
    return dialogText;
});
```

You'll probably want to detect where you're going via e.target.